# Confused about っていうのが and っていうのも

Tags: grammar, particles, listening

So far, my understanding is that these two expressions are a contracted form of というのは， whose common application is to explain the meaning of something.

In a JLPT listening video, I heard this:

> **M**: 今朝新聞で見たんだけどある調査によると 日本では70%近くの人が毎月貯金をしてるんだって
> **F**: 多いね
> **M**: 年を取ってからの生活のために**っていうのが**一番多くて家とか車とか高価な買い物のため**っていうのも**多かったよ

This seems highly unconventional - I guess the っていうのが is trying to refer to the survey above, but it couldn't get any more different from the [Phrase]+というのは[Explanation] format I'm used to.

Can I trouble anyone to 'break down' the 3rd sentence and explain how this functions?

Comment: You can think this の ("one") is a substitute for something like 回答. Do you understand it if it were `「生活のため」という回答が一番多い`?

Answer (score 1):

This is where が picks out a solitary item to stand out.

> 年を取ってからの生活のためにっていうのが一番多くて

> [Saving] for life after one gets old was the greatest [number] and

> 家とか車とか高価な買い物のためっていうのも多かったよ

> Many were also [saving] for [purchasing] a home, a car, and other high cost items.

が makes it clear that saving for one's later years stood out.  Much like if one were to say,

> 私が学生です

vs

> 私は学生です

Here in the first one, you're saying "I'm the one who's the student" and the second is just saying "I'm a student".